# ReCaptcha doesn't show up on Facebox

Tags: php, ajax, recaptcha, facebox

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php'); 
$publickey = "API_KEY"; // you got this from the signup page 
?> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.form.js"></ 
script> 
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
                $('#inquiry').ajaxForm({ 
                        target: '#error', 
                        success: function() { 
                        $('#error').fadeIn('slow'); 
                        } 
                }); 
        }); 
        var RecaptchaOptions = { 
                theme : 'clean' 
        }; 
    </script> 
<div class="top_area">Inquiry Form</div> 
    <div id="search_area"> 
    </div> 
<div style="overflow-y: hidden;"> 
<form name="inquiry" id="inquiry" action="asadadasd.php" 
method="post"> 
<div id="error"></div> 
<table align="center"> 
<tr> 
        <td valign="top" align="right"></td> 
        <td> 
                <?php 
                  echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey); 
                ?> 
        </td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
        <td valign="top"></td> 
        <td> 
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" 
style="height: 30px; background: #ab2220; border: 2px #fff solid; 
color: #fff;" /> 
        </td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form> 
</table> 
</form> 
</div>
```

That's the code I have as of now but recaptcha plugin doesn't show up 
am I missing something? 
Thanks guys, 
You are so awesome

Comment: Is that literally the code you are using or have you changed the publickey variable to API_KEY just for this site?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the recaptcha AJAX API on facebox. Include the AJAX script in your page (Not the page facebox will display. Put it in the containing page) Then use the recaptcha api as specified in the docs.

http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#AJAX